# Ansible regex_replace insert value after regex match

Tags: ansible, jinja2, regexp-replace

I have a version variable, which I need to split and insert a . in between

I tried this

```
ansible localhost  -e version=300 -m debug -a "msg={{ version  | regex_replace('\d{1,2}', '.\g<0>' ) }}"
```

But the o/p is

```
TASK [debug] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg: .30.0
```

There is a . getting **.30.0** added in the first place. I  can use regex_repace to remove the first. after that. 
But is there any other better way? Why is pattern putting the decimal point in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Q: *"Why is pattern putting the decimal point in the first place?"*

A: Regex `\d{1,2}` matches one or two digits. Given the string `300` this regex matches the first two digits`30`. It will be replaced with `.\g<0>` which gives

```
.30
```

Next match is `0` because only one digit has left. The replacement gives

```
.0
```

Put together the result is

```
.30.0
```

> Q: *"Is there any way I can directly insert "." (dot) after the second place? ie 30.0?"*

A: For example the play

```
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    my_string: '300'
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ my_string[0:2] ~ '.' ~ my_string[2:] }}"
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ my_string[:-1] ~ '.' ~ my_string[-1] }}"
```

gives

```
"msg": "30.0"
"msg": "30.0"
```

Comment: is there anyway I can directly insert the .(dot) after the second place? 
ie      30.0

Comment: this serves my purpose, thank you. Where can I find documentation on this usage? This seems very different from the regex_replace module. Sorry for being dumb!

Comment: See [Python regex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html).

Comment: See [3.3.1. Slices](http://www.openbookproject.net/books/bpp4awd/ch03.html#slices).

Comment: just playing around & was able to accomplish this with the positive look behind, adding here if someone is interested
`ansible localhost  -e version=300 -m debug -a "msg={{ version   | regex_replace('(?<=\d{2}).', '.\g<0>') }}"`